# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a error when save new data. I am using AngularJS

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

**app.js**

```
Call23.factory('data', function ($resource) {
 return $resource('/api/Person1/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method:'PUT' } });
 });
   var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location, data, $http) {
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.search = function () {
    data.query({
        offset: $scope.offset,
        limit: $scope.limit,
        q: $scope.query,
        p: $scope.part
    },
        function (something) {
            $scope.users = $scope.users.concat(something);
        });
     };
    };
 var CreateCtrl = function ($scope, $location, data) {
$scope.save = function () {
    data.save($scope.lis, function () {
        $location.path('/')
    });
    };
```

Can you please assist me here in this error.